# Recording of refunds for an event

Tags: stripe, refund

For an upcoming event, I gave a number of our members refunds using Stripe. These refunds were recorded in the personal dashboard of each member, but they still appear as paid attendees for the event, even after receiving their refund, which causes confusion

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE!  There are many reasons why one might refund an event participant payment which would affect how the event registration is recorded.  For example, if you refund because someone cancels you also want to cancel the event registration.  If they have paid but they are a speaker you might refund the payment and want to change their role from 'attendee' to 'speaker'.

Conversely, just because someone cancels does not necessarily mean you want to refund the payment.

What is the reason for the refund?  How do you want their registrations to show now? If they are not attending you could select those registrations and set the status to 'Cancelled'

Comment: We refund payment because the member decides they will no longer be participating in the event. Therefore we want that member removed from the list of event participants and wanted to avoid having to record all these changes manually, due to high workload, risk of error etc.